# Algorithm does not sort array as expected

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort, data-partitioning

I got the following algorithm with [3, 7, 5 ,2, 1, 4, 8] input. It is said that is  part of QuickSort and it constructs a partition position.. The output should be [3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 8]
[image]

I used the following python code:

```
def partition(x, s, d):
    v = x[s]
    i = s-1
    j = d+1
    while i < j:
        while True:
            i = i+1 
            if x[i] >=v:
                break
        while True:
            j = j-1 
            if x[j] <=v:
                break 
        if (i<j):
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
            
    print (x)
    return j
    
    
x = [3, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 8]
partition(x, 1, 6)
```

I can't get **[3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 8]** which is allegedly the right result here.
Please help, I tried with different values for s and d which most probably stands for left and right.

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 8]

Comment: I agree with the comment that was just removed that the 2nd parameter here should be a zero, else you don't sort the first number..

Comment: I removed my comment because if the second parameter is 0 line 6, `UNTIL x[i] >= v` has an index out of range error. @Surt

Comment: @LaytonGB I thought so too, but the algorithm actually increment before checking the index.

Answer (score 2):

This is Partition Algorithm of Quicksort.

Since we use a `while` loop instead of a `do.. while` (This is what is mentioned in your algorithm `REPEAT... UNTIL`), we don't need to decrement `s` and increment `d`.

```
def partition(x, s, d):
    v = x[s]
    i = s
    j = d
    
    while i < j:
        while x[i] <= v:
            i += 1
        
        while x[j] >= v:
            j -= 1

        if (i<j):
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
            
    print(x)
    return j
    
    
x = [3, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 8]
partition(x, 0, 6)
```

```
Output:

[3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

When `i` and `j` are defined, they are equal to the start index minus 1, and the end index plus 1. If these indexes are used they will be out of range so you will get an error. Hence, when the code arrives at the `REPEAT ... UNTIL` sections, the minus 1 and plus 1 are immediately undone. To avoid this issue I've used this code:

```py
lis = [3,7,5,2,1,4,8]

def partition(x,s,d):
    v = x[s]
    i = s
    j = d
    while i < j:
        while x[i] <= v:
            i += 1
        while x[j] >= v:
            j -= 1
        if i < j:
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    return j
    
position = partition(lis, 0, 6)
print(position)
print(lis)
```

Output:

```py
2
[3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 8]
```

I believe the position can be used to partition the list and sort it further, but due to the lack of information I'm not sure how best to do that.

Thanks to the other answer I believe the confusion was arising from the `REPEAT ... UNTIL` condition statements. By making my statements `<=` rather than just `<` I've gained the desired output.

Comment: Doing away with the silliness of -1 also works. And you don't need the aux, the OPs swap should be good.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def partition(x, s, d):
    v = x[s]
    i = s-1
    j = d+1
    while i < j:
        while True:
            i = i+1 
            if x[i] >v: #--->
                break
        while True:
            j = j-1 
            if x[j] <v: #--->
                break
        if (i<j):
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
            
    print (x)
    return j
    
    
x = [3, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 8]
partition(x, 0, len(x)-1) #---->
```

```
[3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 8]
```